# Proving an infinite norm minimization problem has finite support (non-convex p-norms)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, norms, non-convex-optimization

Consider an optimization problem over infinite variables:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{x}~& {\left\lVert{x}\right\rVert }_p
\\
\text{s.t}~& \left\langle x, a_n\right\rangle \ge 1~,~\forall n=1,\dots,N
\end{align}
$$
where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $x$ and $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{N}$ are all **infinite-length** vectors, 
the $a$'s are constant vectors, and ${\left\lVert{\cdot}\right\rVert }_p$ is the $p$-norm.

**Clarification on the constraints** (edited): we can assume each entry of the constraint vectors is bounded by a constant $r>0$, that is $\forall{n\in\left[{N}\right]},i: \left\lvert{a_n\left({i}\right)}\right\rvert \le r$. Unfortunately, we *cannot* assume that these entire vectors $\left\{{a_n}\right\}_{n=1}^{N}$
are bounded under some norms.

**Prove:** *if the minimum is attainable*, then there exists an optimal solution $x^*$ whose support, i.e. $\text{supp}\left(x^*\right)$, is finite (where the support of a vector is its non-zero entries).

I am especially interested in cases where $0<p<1$, **when the objective function is no longer convex**.

---

When $p=1$, there are some known proofs (*e.g.* on [Wei 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05369)), but as far as I understand they all use the **convexity** of the $p$-norm when $p\ge 1$, *e.g.* to apply strong duality to the dual problem and show that there are optimal solutions with a support of at most $N$.

I started reading about quasi-convex optimization (since $p$-norms for $p\in\left[0,1\right]$ are quasi-convex), but I was thinking maybe there is a simple solution I am missing out.

---

**Update**: since it is already known for $p=1$, one could (at least practically) expect the sparsity would only improve for lower values of $p$. So if there are some theoretical results in that spirit, they could be relevant.

---

Any help or directions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think a feasible way is to use directional derivatives in feasible directions: If $x^*$ is a solution and $e$ is a vector such that $x^*+e$ does still fulfill the inequality constraints (i.e. $\langle e,a_n\rangle\leq 0$) and use that $\sum |x_i^*|^p\leq \sum |x_i^*+e_i|^p$.

Comment: @Dirk Thank you for the answer, but I am not sure I follow.  Isn't the inequality you've written trivial since $x^*$ is an optimal solution?

Comment: well, and what are conditions on vectors $a_n$? Say, if $N=1$ and $a_1=(1,2,3,\dots)$, the infimum of $\|x\|_p$ is 0.

Comment: Sure, but that's one inequality you can work with, e.g. you could try to plug in $te$ instead of $e$ and divide through $t$ and let $t\to 0$ and maybe arrive at some contradiction if too many $x^*_i$ are non-zero.

Comment: @FedorPetrov nice example! I now clarified that the vectors $a_n$ are bounded entry-wise.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk for your help! It seems your direction summarized Fedor's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p=1$, $N=1$ and $a_1=(1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,\ldots)$, the infimum equals 1 and is not achieved on a finitely supported vector (moreover, it is not achieved at all).

However if $0<p<1$ and the minimizer $x$ exists, it must have finite support (namely, of size at most $N$). To prove this, assume the contrary. Without loss of generality $x_1,\dots,x_{N+1}$ are positive. Choose a non-zero vector $b=(b_1,\dots,b_{N+1},0,0,\dots)$ orthogonal to all $a_i$'s. Choose small $t$ so that $x_i-t|b_i|>0>0$ for all $i=1,\dots,N+1$. Then by concavity of the function $x^p$ we have $$x_1^p+\ldots+x_{N+1}^p> \frac12\left((x_1+tb_1)^p+\ldots+(x_{N+1}+tb_{N+1})^p+\\+(x_1-tb_1)^p+\ldots+(x_{N+1}-tb_{N+1})^p\right).$$ Therefore one of the vectors $x\pm tb$ has smaller $p$-norm than $x$.

For $p>1$ the claim is completely false. Say, if $p=2$, $N=1$, the minimum is achieved on the vector proportional to $a_1$.

Comment: @Itay yes, of course

Comment: Again, nice counter example. In the light of your comment, I guess a more accurate claim should be "*if optimal solutions are attainable*, then there exists such a solution with a finite support".

Comment: I will however reread the two references (proving it for $p=1$) I gave in the comments to the other answer. It is interesting if the explicitly narrow down their proof to cases when the solution is attainable.

Comment: One could still say on that example is that there exist $K>0$ such that for any $L$, the solution of the optimal problem restricted to $[0,L]$ is on a support of size bounded by $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much, works great

Answer (score 3):

If one use Lagrange multipliers, there exist $\mu_1, \mu_2 , \cdots \mu_N$ such that $$ \begin{cases} p|x^*(i)|^{p-1}=\sum_{n=1}^N \mu_n a_n(i) \quad\text{  or}\\ |x^*(i)|=0\end{cases}$$ for all $i$. If $0<p<1$, and for every $n$, $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}a_n(i)= 0$ and then $$ \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\big(\frac{1}{p}\sum_n \mu_n a_n(i)\big)^{1/(p-1)}=\infty$$ but obviously $x^*(i)$ is bounded so $x^*(i)=0$ for large $i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, you say that $a_n\left(i\right)$ goes to zero because you implicitly assume $\left\lVert{a_n}\right\rVert$ is bounded by some constant under some norm. I cannot assume this in my task, and I now added a clarification to the question. Moreover, even if it was true, what happens to this proof if only one coordinate of each vector $a_n$ is nonzero? I guess these limits turn undefined.

Comment: I think that for $a$ merely in $\ell^\infty$ (i.e. only bounded but not decaying to zero) you will not have that $x^*$ must be sparse.

Comment: @Dirk Even though it is true for $p=1$?

Comment: Are you sure that this is also true for $p=1$? I don't think so… If I remember correctly, most papers that work with $a$'s of infinite length assume $a\in\ell^2$ or some other summability condition which implies decay to zero.

Comment: In [Wei 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05369) they use in equation (3.5) $a_n\triangleq \phi\left(x_n\right)$, where $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ (notice $x_n$ are examples, unlike our $x$). Then they show 
  that an equivalent optimization problem to our problem with $p=1$ (eq. B.1 in Appendix B), has finite support (Lemma B.1).

Comment: I also believe this is similar to the result of [Rosset et al. 2007](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/RossetEtAlCOLT07.pdf) in Section 3 (referring to the problem defined in eq. (4)).

Comment: If $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}x^*(i)=0$ then at least one of the $a_n$ is not bounded (in contradiction to your assumption).

Comment: Thank you @RaphaelB4!